# In the theorem is it necessary for ring $R$ to be commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

According to the statement of theorem that a commutative ring $R$ with prime characteristic $p$ satisfies

$$\begin{align}
(a+b)^{p^n} = a^{p^n} + b^{p^n}
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
(a-b)^{p^n} = a^{p^n} - b^{p^n}
\end{align}$$

Where a,b $\in$ $R$, n  $\geq 0$ and n $\in \mathbb{Z}$

I have thoroughly checked the proof many times but I don't understand why the condition of commutativity is important.

Comment: Say $p=2$. Then $(a+b)^2=a^2+ab+ba+b^2$. You want to consolidate the two middle terms into $2ab$ so that they die, but you can only do that if $a$ and $b$ commute.

Comment: A "useful" generalization is that the claims hold without the commutativity assumption, if we instead assume that $a=1$. It is enough that $ab=ba$, and this is given when $a=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the polynomial ring in noncommuting variables $R=F_2\langle x,y \rangle$ where $F_2$ is  the field of two elements.

Everything clearly has additive order $2$, but $(x+y)^2=x^2+xy+yx+y^2\neq x^2+y^2$. If the last equality did hold then $xy+yx=0$, but $xy$ and $yx$ are linearly independent in this $F_2$ algebra, so it cannot be the case.

Answer (score 2):

The commutative property is key in proving (for example, by induction) the [Binomial Formula for commutative rings $A$ with $1$](http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/09/12/the-binomial-theorem-holds-in-any-commutative-ring/):

$$ (a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} a^k b^{n-k} $$
for all $a,b\in A$.

In prime characteristic $p$, we can then use $p | {p^n \choose k}$, $k<p^n$ and $k>0$.